# Issues with Javascript Buildorder

Tags: javascript

I recently came across this question and was trying to solve this problem.

**Question:**

> 1. Implement getBuildOrder to return an array of package names that can be built in order, such that no package is built before its
>      dependencies are built. (Just like **package.json** for example)
> 2. What is your approach?
> 3. What critical edge cases should you consider? (circular dependencies)
> 4. How do you plan to detect circular dependencies in your approach?

```js
const example = [
    {
        name: "cat",
        dependencies: {
            dog: "latest",
            horse: "latest"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "dog",
        dependencies: {}
    },
    {
        name: "horse",
        dependencies: {
            bird: "latest"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "bird",
        dependencies: {}
    },
    {
        name: "bear",
        dependencies: {
            "horse": "latest"
        }
    }
];

function getBuildOrder(packages) { // Code goes here };
```

**This was my solution (Approach):**

```
function getBuildOrder(packages) {
    const result = new Set();
    const remaining = [];

    packages.forEach(each => {
        const { name, dependencies } = each;
        if(Object.keys(dependencies).length === 0) result.add(name);
        else remaining.push(each);
    });

    remaining.forEach(each => {
        Object.keys(each.dependencies).forEach(key => result.add(key));
        result.add(each.name);
    });

    return Array.from(result);
}
```

However, I don't think I'm on the right path. I want to understand the right way of implementing something like this (With recursion).

How do we detect cycles in this case?

Comment: Objects don't have a specific order, unless the are Arrays or Array Like Objects.

Comment: @StackSlave Assume that you are implementing a `package.json` parser that would fetch dependencies first before fetching the actual package. The goal is to implement a logic like this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const example=[{name:"cat",dependencies:{dog:"latest",horse:"latest"}},{name:"dog",dependencies:{}},{name:"horse",dependencies:{bird:"latest"}},{name:"bird",dependencies:{}},{name:"bear",dependencies:{horse:"latest"}}]

function getBuildOrder(packages) { 
    let ordrd = packages.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(b.dependencies).includes(a.name) ? -1 : 1)
    return ordrd.map(obj => obj.name)
}

console.log(getBuildOrder(example))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. `Array.sort` is a O(NlogN) operation. Can we make it faster than nLogN?

Comment: Also, how do we handle cycles in this case? If they are circular dependencies? Curious to see if you had some thoughts around that. @symlink